# Why GetIntent is not working for link in adnroid?

Tags: java, android

I have tried a code where I'm trying to get URLs that are shared by the users through other applications. I want to get the URL and then paste that URL into my android activity's `EditText`. I have tried the below code this code shows my app when I click on share in other apps but it not opening the activity and filling the shared data into `EditText`. Below is my code that i have tried -

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
```

**activity_geturl.xml**

```
<EditText
                        android:id="@+id/urlinput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_37sdp"
                        android:background="@drawable/txt_bg"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="Paste link here"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
```

**GeturlActivity.java**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_geturl);


        boolean isActivityLaunchedFromActionSend = Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(getIntent().getAction());
        boolean isLinkData = getIntent().getType() != null && getIntent().getType().startsWith("text/") && getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) != null && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)).matches();

        if (isActivityLaunchedFromActionSend && isLinkData) {
            String sentLink = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.urlinput);
            editText.setText(sentLink);
        }
}
```

Please note that the activity to which i'm sending shared data is not main activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try intent-filter like this :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```